# How to select all rows into table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table with pagination. I use this JavaScript to select all rows into the table:
Main checkbox:

```
<h:column id="selection_column">
    <f:facet name="header">
         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="checkall"/>
    </f:facet>
</h:column>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $(document).delegate(".checkall", "click", function(event) {
              $(this).closest("table").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that when I use it only the rows into the first page are selected. The rows into the second page and so on are not selected. How I can fix this?

EDIT

I have an idea but I don't know is it going to work: I can create a checkbox(lets call it main checkbox) which when it's selected all rows are selected. I tested it - once selected this checkbox is always selected when I shift the pages. But I need a JavaScript code which checks during load time if the main checkbox is selected then all checkboxes are selected. Can you help me to rewrite the JavaScritp this way, please?

Comment: What type of pagination? Is the content on the page already, just hidden until its "page" is accessed? Or are you going out and grabbing new content asynchronously? Is the page online?

Comment: The page uses Java Server Faces. It uses lazy loading(when I switch pages SQL query takes new rows of data every time). It's not online.

Comment: Simple, then: you can't select DOM elements that aren't in the DOM-tree. just as you can't read books that are back at the library while you're sitting at home :)

Comment: Post updated. Maybe there is a solution.